# Should drip edge be nailed to fascia? Should it wrap around at corners?

Tags: roofing

The roofer nailed the drip edge at most out side corners. It also doesn’t appear the the drip edge wraps behind. Is it supposed to? Should it be nailed? At the inside corners, there is a gap where drip edge doesn’t meet. It seems that water would penetrate there?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]!

Comment: Pictures of the areas in question would go a _long_ way toward helping people understand the situations and indicate if they've been done correctly

Comment: Some pictures would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Drip edge in my experiences has never been nailed to the fascia. It could be, but it is unnecessary and unsightly. The open corners you are referring to are merely cosmetic.

To my knowledge drip edge is not a requirement in some cases. In those places, is a good idea at the least because it gets the water to be cast off a bit farther off the facias and rakes. Shingles when installed properly, will do this on its own. In high wind, very high wind conditions it may be a requirement along with a peel and stick membrane/and or caulk sealant to keep the shingles from blowing off.

In addition when the drip edge is installed, it's nailing can be minimal. The roofing when nailed will provide the rest of the fastening needed to hold the drip edge.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m trying to add some photos from my phone, but they appear to be duplicating. After posting, I went on the roof to look around. There are shingles nailed to the roof vent with the nail hole siliconed. Also, they must’ve damaged part of the chimney when installing flashing and nailed it together with silicone. Is water likely to get in?

Comment: That would need a pic to make the best determination. In various areas the nails will be exposed, they simply cannot be hidden, In those cases it is necessary to apply a good grade caulk over the heads. This is prevalent around chimneys. The nails hold the flashing, the caulk seals out the water.

Comment: @Speechpath70458 take some pics of your chimney and post a _new question_ asking about that. The answers may be the same, they may be different, but the questions are definitely different